# Passive sentence contruction

Tags: passive

Wie wird eine Passiv-Form  aus folgendem Beispielsatz aufgebaut?

Auf der Autobahn kann man sehr schnell fahren.

Ich habe ihn selbst formuliert, aber ich bin nicht sicher ob es richtig oder nicht. So habe ich formuliert:

Auf der Autobahn kann es sehr schnell gefahren werden.

Comment: Lass das _es_ weg, dann pastt's.

Comment: Lass ein t weg und tu ein s dazu, πάντα ῥεῖ - dann passt auch deins. :-))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Auf der Autobahn kann **man** sehr schnell fahren.

*Man* ist bereits ein Füll-Subjekt. Der Passivsatz kommt also ohne diesen Satzteil aus.

> Auf der Autobahn kann sehr schnell gefahren werden.
>
> Sehr schnell gefahren werden kann auf der Autobahn.

Du brauchst in beiden Fällen kein *es*. Das *es* ist allenfalls als Füller notwendig, um die Satzbildungsregel *Verb an zweiter Stelle* zu erfüllen:

> Es kann auf der Autobahn sehr schnell gefahren werden.

Comment: Gemeint ist sicher: Der *Aktivsatz* kommt ohne diesen Satzteil aus.

Comment: Nein. Stünde im Aktivsatz statt *man* z.B. *Peter*, müsste der gleichwertige Passivsatz *Peter* auch in irgendeiner Form enthalten, z.B. als *von/durch Peter*. Steht im Aktivsatz hingegen *man*, braucht man kein *"von man"*.

Comment: Ich hatte den Satz falsch verstanden. Allerdings finde ich den Ausdruck "Füll-Subjekt" nicht sehr glücklich. Der trifft eigentlich nur auf "es" zu.